# How to convert value into key & another key into value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

This is my array of Object. I want to convert my first value into key & Second value into value only. Please go through question and i have also attached my desired output.

```
 [
  {
    "name": "Unknown",
    "value": "RAHUL"
  },
  {
    "name": "FirstName",
    "value": "WILLEKE LISELOTTE"
  },
  {
    "name": "LastName",
    "value": "DE BRUIJN"
  }
]
```

I want my Object as

```
{
"Unknown": "RAHUL"

},
{
"FirstName": "WILLEKE LISELOTTE"
},
{
"LastName": "DE BRUIJN"
}
```

Comment: `I want my Object as` that's not an object, it's several objects separated by commas

Answer (score 0):

***IF*** you mean to create a new array, then simply map the original array. You don't need to create a new array and push into it, that's just redundant code:

```js
const testData = [{
    "name": "Unknown",
    "value": "RAHUL"
  },
  {
    "name": "FirstName",
    "value": "WILLEKE LISELOTTE"
  },
  {
    "name": "LastName",
    "value": "DE BRUIJN"
  }
];

const newData = testData.map(nameObject => {
  return {
    [nameObject.name]: nameObject.value
  }
});
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Like in the dupe target

Comment: Thanks - I did look but didn't see that specific Q/A - good find @Andreas

Answer (score -1):

You just have to use brackets for [value.name] to perform achieve this.

```
var arr = []

testdata.map((value) => {
    arr.push({ [value.name]: value.value })
})
```

Comment: You asked a question then you answered it yourself? why asking if you already have the answer?

Comment: @AdilBimzagh [That's totally valid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Although in this case there are definitely already multiple other questions with the exact same problem.

Comment: This results in an array. OP said he wants an object.

Comment: @James _This_ is the OP o.O

Comment: @Andreas understood.  Point still stands.

Comment: If you're not going to use the return value of `.map()` than `.map()` is not the right tool.